# How to set up different domains based on stage with serverless-domain-manager plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to set up different, custom domains in serverless with `serverless-domain-manager` plugin.

I've followed this tutorial:
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/

but the example doesn't show how to set up more than one custom domain.

In my `serverless.yml` file I have:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  customDomain:
    basePath: ''
    domainName: MY_DOMAIN_HERE
    stage: dev
    createRoute53Record: true
```

How can I add another domain? For example, for `prod` stage?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even though serverless.yml doesn't support conditional logic, it is possible to simulate conditions.

In `serverless.yml` add:

```
custom:
  domain:
    dev: MY_DEV_DOMAIN
    prod: MY_PROD_DOMAIN
  customDomain:
    basePath: ''
    domainName:  ${self:custom.domain.${opt:stage}}
    stage: ${opt:stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
```

Depending on the `sls deploy --stage` parameter, either the `dev` or `prod` domain will be configured.

More info on conditional logic:
https://forum.serverless.com/t/conditional-serverless-yml-based-on-stage/1763